# Dada una lista de números enteros no negativos y una suma objetivo, encuentre un par de números que sumen a la suma objetivo

Tags: javascript

```
function findPairForSum(array, number) {

//que funcion puede crear? con que metodos?

}

findPairForSum([0,12,3,4,5],7)

console.log([3,4])//**como podria hallar este resultado?**
```

Comment: Muy buenos dias Leyla, para poder ayudarte deberás añadir que es lo que has intentado y que problemas has encontrado.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con dos bucles por ejemplo:

```
function findPairForSum(array, number){
  var resultado = [];
  array.forEach(num => {
    array.forEach(num2 => {

        if(num + num2 == number){ //comprobamos si la suma de los numeros son iguales    
          resultado.push(num.toString() + " , " + num2.toString());
        }

    })
  }); // tambien puedes usar for of

  return resultado;

}
```

Y con eso debería darte el resultado 3,4.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var numero= 7;
var sum=[0,12,3,4,5];
var resultado=[];
  for(i = 0 ; i < sum.length; i++){
      var a = sum[i];
      if(resultado.length==0){
        for(j = 0 ; j < sum.length; j++){
        var b = sum[j];
          if(parseInt(a)+parseInt(b)==numero){
          resultado=[a,b];
          console.log(resultado);
           }
         }
      }
      else{
        i=sum.length;
      }
  }
```

Este código me da como resultado en la consola 3,4 y ahora te lo explicare un poco:
La variable **numero** es el numero del cual quieres hallar dos números que den su suma, la variable **sum** es el array que contiene los demás números enteros los cuales tienes que sumar y obtener el resultado de la variable **numero**, luego declaramos **resultado** que es un array vació que nos imprimirá el resultado. Creamos un ciclo for que funcionara hasta que la variable del ciclo **i** llegue hasta la cantidad de datos que tiene nuestro array **sum**, luego declaramos la variable **a** esta variable almacena el dato que tiene el array en la posición de **i**, la siguiente condicional if es para saber si aun no se ha obtenido un resultado, si es así creamos otro ciclo for porque necesitamos dos numeros del array **sum** que al sumarse obtengamos el resultado de la variable **numero** así que en este ciclo hacemos lo mismo pero con la variable **j**, luego declaramos la variable **b**, esta obtendrá también el valor del dato que se encuentra en el array en la posición de **j**, luego para obtener nuestro resultado preguntamos si el dato del array que se encuentra en la variable **a** sumado con el dato del array que se encuentra en la variable **b** es igual al numero, si es así llenamos nuestro array **resultado** con los dos datos **a** y **b** y lo escribimos en la consola.